# How to monitor new posts on channel with Telegraf API?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm creating a Telegram bot, and want it to send me any message when there is new post on channel I made it to monitor. 
Are there any trigger in Telegraf API for new channel posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question solved. 
Just needed to use `ctx.channelPost`.
Here is full description of that API - https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=context

Comment: Did you find any good examples how to use that?